# Command-line access to remote MySQL server

Tags: macos, ssh, mysql

I administer a website on a remote, shared host.  My web host offers MySQL, and I am able to access this from my Mac OS X computer using a GUI program, [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com).  That works great.

But I want to script some queries, and Sequel Pro is not scriptable.  What should I do?

I've read about tunneling to mysql via SSH.  I have shell access to the server, with an SSH key on my Mac, so

ssh jerrykri@123.456.789.123 -p 7978

gets me in.  Should tunneling the MySQL port 3306 work?  Like this?

ssh jerrykri@123.456.789.123 -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306

(It "times out" after a minute.)

Do I need to install mysql on my Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the MySQL server, you need to modify the file *my.cnf*, whose location depends on OS: in Debian, it is in /etc/mysql, for instance. Edit it, find the line

```
 [mysqld]
```

and add to it the following text:

```
 [mysqld]
 user            = mysql
 pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 port            = 3306
 basedir         = /usr
 datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
 tmpdir          = /tmp
 language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
 bind-address    = The_IP_of_YOUR_MySQL_Server
 # skip-networking
```

Here, what is important is that you comment out the line *skip-networking*, and that you insert, in the line *bind-address*, the IP of the server. Save, restart mysql (again, this depends on OS), access MySQL with the usual

```
  mysql -u root -p mysql
```

and allow access from your own remote IP to the existing database:

```
  mysql> update db set Host='Your_own_remote_IP' where Db='webdb';
  mysql> update user set Host='Your_own_remote_IP' where user='webadmin';
```

Now go back to your remote system, and test the new functionality:

```
 mysql -u webadmin –h The_IP_of_theMySQL_Server –p
```

For this to work, of course, you need a MySQL client on your Mac. You can now script your own MySQL queries, for instance, in a bash script as follows:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  result=`mysql -h The_IP_of_theMySQL_Server --user=webadmin --password=Your_Password --skip-column-names -e "select id from mydb.mytable where myattribute = 3"`
```

EDIT:

This is required if you want to connect remotely directly to the MySQL server. If you just want to script your queries locally (*i.e.*, on the server), then *MySQL* client will do. You can find an introduction [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html).

Comment: Thank you, Marius.  And, wow.  I think I may need to find another way because, for starters, this is a shared host and I don't have access to /etc.  Does this really have to be *so* hard, though?  The GUI program that I mentioned, Sequel Pro, works fine and I don't recall that I ever had to tweak the host.  All it needed was account information and credentials.  I just want a command-line version of Sequel Pro.  (I know, it's open source so I could fork and write one myself, but I was hoping to get this done tomorrow.)

Comment: @JerryKrinock Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using ssh you can run commands remotely.  So if you want to script some queries, this is one way to do it.  Maybe not what you're looking for, but an option to know about

Let's say host B is your sql server.  host A is the client you want to run your queries from

On host B, put your queries in files, e.g. create a "test.sql" file.  In my case I just put "show databases"

Then from host A you can do

ssh [options] "[command to run]"

Set up passwordless login with ssh (using ssh-rsa authentication).  Using "ssh-keygen" and "ssh-copy-id".  You can test this out by then doing

ssh [options] "ls" and see if it returns "ls" results of host B

From there you can do

ssh [options] "mysql [options] < test.sql"

Does that make sense?

You would also need to put a password on your mysql command which you might not be a fan of, not very secure.  I have not experimented with other "passwordless" login to mysql, maybe there is another way to do that portion.